# how to set thousand separator (empty space) and decimal separator (comma) and take number of decimals from database field in ssrs?

Tags: ssrs-2008, locale, reporting-services, numeric, decimal

I'm preparing a report in MS SQL Report Builder.
I have data fields:

```
Value        Decimals
12345.3456   3
3455.34      3 
654677       0
145.4565727  6
```

I need to round Value according to Decimals and change thousand separator to empty space and decimal point to comma (it is language property sv-SE). The textbox output on report must have values like these:

```
Value
12 345,346
3 455,34  
654 677    
145,456573
```

I haven't found any way to set thousand and decimals separators (language property), but to get number of decimals from database field. 
Does anybody have suggestions how to get it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Format(Sum(Fields!CreditAmountCur.Value),"## ### ##0.000000")
```

For me i used 2 numbers after the point :

```
Format(Sum(Fields!CreditAmountCur.Value),"## ### ##0.00")
```

hope it will work for you !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the FormatCurrency function? You can pass an argument to this function to specify the number of decimal places. Instead of hard-coding a value, use the database field.

Comment: When I pass an argument then it becomes automatically custom format and then regional language settings are not taken into account any more. So thousand separator remains comma and decimals separator dot.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an expression on the format property.

Something like:

```
="### ###," & StrDup(Fields!Decimals.Value, "#")
```

Comment: In this case thousand separator is yes empty space and decimal separator comma, but there are no decimal places on output.

Answer (score 0):

It is surprisingly hard! You can use these expressions for the value:

```
=replace(Format(12345.3456, "## ### ##0.###")   ,".",",")
=replace(Format(3455.34,    "## ### ##0.###")   ,".",",")
=replace(Format(654677,     "## ### ##0.###")   ,".",",")
=replace(Format(145.4565727,"## ### ##0.######"),".",",")
```